# JQuery time picker not working at second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a modal dialog which contains a form loaded via ajax. In the form is a tim field which is populated using the jquery timepicker. All works well if I open the dialog one time. If I load the dialog a second time without refreshing the page the timepicker not working

here is my code

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control timepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtTime" />
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtTime").timepicker({
             twentyFour: false, title:'Time', showSeconds: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question itself may be rather unclear, I'll try to provide two scenarios that might address your issue.

**If you are replacing elements within the DOM...**

If your existing element is being either replaced or removed and re-added to the DOM, you'll need to make sure that you re-wire up your timepicker function to target the most recent instance of that element in the DOM

```
// Open your dialog here and re-write your elements

// This will target the new element that should now be present in the DOM 
$("#txtTime").timepicker({ twentyFour: false, title:'Time', showSeconds: false });
```

Without knowing the exact details of how you are displaying or disposing of the dialog and its contents, it could be difficult to determine the best way to handle this, but explicitly instantiating the picker each time should ensure that it works as expected.

**If you are actually posting the page and reloading it...**

In instances where you are submitting a form or refreshing the page, it's worth noting that your timepicker will not persist during the process and will need to be re-instantiated when the page initially loads :

```
$(function(){
      // This will ensure that when the page loads, your timepicker works
      $('#txtTime').timepicker({ ... });
});
```